# Как обновить только несколько полей в таблице используя JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, jpa

Использую JPA + Spring Data + Hibernate для работы с данными.
Сущность EmployeeJpaBean имеет такие вот поля:

```
@Column(name = "empl_name", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "empl_address", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String address;

//ещё много других полей-примитивов.

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "employee")
private Set<TaskJpaBean> tasks = new HashSet<>();
```

У меня есть метод в контроллере, который вызывает конвертор и который в свою очередь преобразует данную JPA сущность в простой JSON с примитивами, но игнорируя поле tasks, т.к. данных в этом поле может быть много. Этот простой JSON с примитивами отправляется на веб страницу где пользователь может изменить какие-либо поля - например имя, адрес, email и т.д. Далее пользовательнаживаем кнопку save и отправляет этот JSON c примитивами обратно на сервер где поля нужно обновить и записать в БД.

**Первое** что пришло в голову - конвертировать JSON в JPA с помощью конвертора. Но это не работает т.к. при записи такой JPA сущности теряются объекты tasks - ведь JSON не имел информации о tasks. Способ оказался нерабочим.

**Второе** что пришло в голову - во время того как обновлённый JSON приходит в контроллер, извлекать JPA сущность по ID. Далее обновлять поля в этой JPA сущности в соответствии с пришедшим JSON. Способ относительно рабочий, но в этом случае придётся обновлять каждое поле вручную. А если у объекта EmployeeJpaBean  будут добавлены новые поля... расширение продукта будет затруднено.

Как нужно грамотно поступать ? Спасибо.

Comment: Во втором случае не обязательно обновлять каждое поле вручную, можно использовать mapper, например Dozer, это вообще хорошая практика. На фронт и с фронта ходят DTO и при записи в базу мапятся маппером в сущности

Answer (score 2):

Первый вариант:

```
Entity entity= em.getReference(Entity.class, id); //em.find(Entity.class, id);
em.getTransaction().begin();
entity.setName("Joe");
entity.setAddress("Address");
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Второй вариант (для сущности без связей подойдет, все поля будут обновляться)

```
void updateEntity (Entity entity){
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.merge(entity);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Третий вариант

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.createQuery("UPDATE Entity SET name =:name, address=: address where id = :id")
    .setParameter("name", name)
    .setParameter("address", address)
    .setParameter("id", id)
    .executeUpdate();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Предпочтение к первому варианту, т.к. все управление полями для обновления сущности идет через Java код, второй вариант не сильно безопасен (можно упустить из виду добавленные или измененные поля разработчиком, особенно тяжелые поля, такие как BLOB или String length = 10000000), третий вариант - много писать кода.

Comment: Я использую Spring Data. А EntityManager - не использую. Ручной вызов транзакций также не использую. Метод merge() мне не подходит, почему - описал в вопросе. Ручное обновление каждого поля тоже не подходит.

Comment: em.getTransaction() это для наглядности, можно заменить на @ Transactional. Первый вариант в Spring Data получаешь сущность (findById(id)), задаешь поля и выходишь из метода с @ Transactional. Третий вариант: использовать @ Query над методом и передавать такой же запрос и те же параметры. При втором варианте (напр. CrudRepository) нет метода update или merge, то придется пользоваться первым или третьим вариантом. Я использую первый вариант для обновления, мне легко поддерживать код, хотя это дело привычки.

Comment: Ага, понятно насчёт замены менеджера на @Transactional. Жаль, похоже придётся использовать второй вариант из моего вопроса (т.е. ручное обновление полей). Спасибо.